# YouTube videos play back at unwatchably fast rate with Safari on the latest Big Sur beta... anyone else?

Tags: safari, video, youtube

I have trouble.  When I try to play YouTube videos, they play super fast.  I'd include a video of the problem but it would be too large.  Suffice it to say that a 24 minute video finishes in less than 5 seconds when I hit the Play button.  This is new with Big Sur.  I just installed beta 9 last night.  I have turned off all extensions, deleted my history, restarted Safari, all to no avail.  The problem happens with Chrome too so might be a QuickTime problem or something underlying.

Comment: Having a similar issue. When watching a YouTube video on my 2019 Mac – the video will play at a normal speed then, seemingly randomly, will start fast forward at maybe 3-5x speed uncontrollably until I refresh the page. This is an odd bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a commonly reported bug that occurs 'sometimes'. Another solution, short of rebooting, is to kill the coreaudiod process.

You can do this in Activity Monitor, or in the Terminal with `sudo killall coreaudiod`

https://9to5mac.com/2019/07/29/macos-fast-video-playback-bug-fix-coreaudiod-video/

Comment: I would just like to add that it isn't always coreaudiod. I had this exact same issue, but no coreaudiod listed in Activity Monitor. I saw an Apple community post mentioning that coreaudiod would have multiple hours of CPU Time in Activity Monitor. I instead had either Microsoft Remote Desktop or another program listed with many hours of CPU Time. I killed those two processes and it resolved the issue immediately. I am not sure which one it was, in all I had killed RDP, Discord, and one other thing and one of those three items fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

"Solved" by rebooting!  Sorry to waste your time... lesson for the next guy I guess!  Cheers.